# How to replace the Community version of Neo4j with the Enterprise version

Tags: neo4j

I have recently downloaded the community version of Neo4J where I was practicing with the program. I have now downloaded the Enterprise version (I was wanting to upload a spread sheet which I could not do in the community version, see here for more info http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/03/importing-data-into-neo4j-spreadsheet.html. The issue is when I try and use the Enterprise version I cannot get it to work as it says it fails to start every time I click on the 'Neo4j' application.

How can I get the Enterprise version to work and replace the Community version?

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall your community edition, and follow http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/ha-setup-tutorial.html to get the Enterprise Edition installed, and point it to the same database directory on the master.

Comment: I guess "apt-get remove neo4j" and then "apt-get install neo4j-enterprise" will do the trick?